# Bootstrap Modal window is closing when clicked on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a Grid inside Modal window. Whenever I click on *Bootstrap 3* Modal window its getting closed. I want that Modal to stay open as I am trying to display loading. I tried by setting `.dialog('show')` and `.show()` but both are not working. I keep getting a message that dialog is not defined.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Below is the code. Modal should stay open when I click on saveGrid button.

```
<div id="GridDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:95%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class=" modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="GridModal">
                <div style="text-align:center" id="loadingIcon"><i class="icon-ui-loading"></i> Please wait..</div>
                <form id="GridForm"></form>
                <div id="errorSummaryGrid" class="form-group alert alert-warning" style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveGrid">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancelGrid" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put together a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ax6uqpce/         Do you have additional behavior attached?

Comment: add `type="button"` to `saveGrid` can solve the problem, if you have the `saveGrid` inside form, without `type` it just submit the form and close the modal